# What is the counter for coins?

Tags: counters

What is the counter for coins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's 枚【まい】.

> 3枚のコイン

Sometimes 個【こ】 is also used in casual situations.

Comment: It's just 枚？ (I thought it might have been 玉 or something like that)
Thanks for that!

Comment: @paullb It might be good to know that the name we call it and the counter we use for it must almost always be different. As we call coins such as 100円玉, 玉 couldn't be its counter.

Comment: 玉 is for round bundles of noodles or round vegetables.